# How to delete duplicates in string for each row

Tags: r

Here is my sample data:

```
V1
"a b c c c d"
"a a b b c d"
"a b c d e f"
```

I want this output:

```
V1
"a b c d"
"a b c d"
"a b c d e f"

paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, split=" "))))
```

gets rid of duplicates from the entire dataframe, while I need it to be row by row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sapply` instead of `unlist`

```
df$V2 <- sapply(strsplit(df$V1, " "), function(x) paste0(unique(x), collapse = " "))

df
#           V1          V2
#1 a b c c c d     a b c d
#2 a a b b c d     a b c d
#3 a b c d e f a b c d e f
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("a b c c c d", "a a b b c d", "a b c d e f"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

We could actually use a regex approach here, e.g.

```
x <- "a a b b c d"
x <- gsub("([a-z])(?: \\1)+, "\\1", x)
x

[1] "a b c d"
```

This uses the approach of matching and capturing every letter in the input, and then replacing it along with any following duplicates with only the single letter.

Note that this approach assumes that the letters in the input are always sorted in some order.  If not, then you might have to stick with your current approach.

To apply to every row of your data frame:

```
apply(V1, 1, function(x) gsub("([a-z])(?: \\1)+, "\\1", x))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `apply` to loop over the rows and get the `unique` elements

```
df$V2 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {x1 <- scan(text = x, what = "")
          paste(x1[!duplicated(x1)], collapse= ' ')})

df
#           V1          V2
#1 a b c c c d     a b c d
#2 a a b b c d     a b c d
#3 a b c d e f a b c d e f
```

---

Or another option is using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
    separate_rows(V1) %>% 
    distinct %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>%
    summarise(V1 = str_c(V1, collapse=" ")) %>% 
    select(V1)
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  V1         
#  <chr>      
#1 a b c d    
#2 a b c d    
#3 a b c d e f
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("a b c c c d", "a a b b c d", "a b c d e f"
   )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```